# Reflecting on a F# module when there is another Type with the same name

Tags: f#

I am trying to get the `MethodInfo` for a function in a module: `PersistentVector.ofSeq`.  The issue I am running into is that there is a generic type defined with the same name as the module: `PersistentVector<'a>`.

I want to do this:

```
let methodInfo = typedefof<PersistentVector>.GetMethod("ofSeq")
let finalMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(itemType)
finalMethod.Invoke(...)
```

But that fails to compile (line 1) with the error: `The type 'FSharpx.Collections.PersistentVector<_>' expects 1 type argument(s) but 0 given.`

If I change line 2 to this:

```
let methodInfo = typedefof<PersistentVector<_>>.GetMethod("ofSeq")
```

That compiles but at runtime returns null since the Type being retrieved is the generic PersistentVector type which does not have an "ofSeq" method.

I can get things to work like this:

```
let pvModuleTypeFullName = "FSharpx.Collections.PersistentVectorModule"
let pvModuleType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typedefof<PersistentVector<_>>).GetType(pvModuleTypeFullName)
let methodInfo = pvModuleType.GetMethod("ofSeq")
let finalMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(itemType)
finalMethod.Invoke(...)
```

But that seems hacky and I am wondering if theres a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a shame that `typeof<_>` can't take a module as an argument, only a type (despite that in the .NET representation modules *are* types).  Here's an alternative approach:

```
open Quotations.Patterns
let finalMethod = 
    let (Lambda(_,Call(None,m,[_]))) = <@ PersistentVector.ofSeq @>
    m.GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(itemType)
...
```

Comment: This is not only an "alternative" approach, but a decidedly better one: this code will break at compile time if/when this API changes, instead of failing at runtime with an unexplained NRE.